# Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Slice<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>' and '[[String : AnyObject]]' UISearch

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

In Swift 4,
 I'm trying to compare the length of the text of an UISearchBar textfield  with a minimum length:

```
 @objc var arrRes = [[String:AnyObject]]()
 var searcharr = [String]()

private func searchBar( searchBar: UISearchBar,  textDidChange searchText: [[String:AnyObject]] )
{
    searcharr = arrRes.filter({$0.prefix(searchText.count) == searchText})
}
```

But I am getting the error:

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Slice<Dictionary>' and '[[String : AnyObject]]'

Comment: `arrRes` seems to be an array of dictionary. You probably want to compare `searchText` against a specific value in each dictionary.

Comment: You need to clearly explain how you want the dictionaries in `arrRes` to be searched so you end up with an array of `String`. And that makes no sense anyway. Why don't you want to end up with a filtered array of dictionary?

Comment: SearchText also changed from string to array , what the requirement then , also you should be clear from the beginning of what you want to achieve

Comment: Apart from the other issues the (array) type of `searcharr` must be the same as `arrRes`.

Answer (score 0):

Correct callback

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar,  textDidChange searchText:String) {
   searcharr = arrRes.keys.filter{(arrRes[$0] as? String)?.hasPrefix(searchText) ?? false }
}
```

//

```
let result =  arrRes.filter {  
  let dic = $0       
  return $0.keys.filter { (dic[$0] as? String )?.hasPrefix(searchText)  ?? false }.count != 0 
}
print(result)
```

Comment: same problem .. because i called ` @objc var arrRes = [[String:AnyObject]]() ` & ` var searcharr = [[String:AnyObject]]() `

Comment: what content of the arrRes , post it's declaration

Comment: it shows error **Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '(AnyObject) throws -> Bool'** at **swift 4**

Comment: not working now error is **Value of type '[[String : AnyObject]]' has no member 'keys'**

Comment: please change the signature of the search bar method as in answer , and post the type of **arrRes ** as from the error it seems it's a dictionary

Comment: Based on the edited question, this isn't right either. It's a really poor question with no details. This is all just guessing until the OP clarifies the requirement.

Comment: @rmaddy I agree ,  the op changed the requirement from dictionary to array

Comment: not working now error is Value of type '[[String : AnyObject]]' has no member 'keys' ??